# How do you achieve this effect? Reducing a photograph to a single tone?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

The effect I want to achieve is demonstrated here: where the person is reduced to a single color, but still has shading etc.

[image: Fitz and the Tantrums album cover]

Comment: Hey welcome to GD.SE what have you tried so far? If we know what part you are stuck at and that you've shown some effort you are more likely to get some answers :)

Comment: Have you tried to google search for something like desaturate and colorize[?](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-effects/gradient-map/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to create a couple of copies of your image. Add a levels layer and play around with the input levels:

[image]

Set this as a clipping mask to your top image. Set this layer's blending mode to something like Vivid Light.

In the next image layer, do as Paolo Gibellini said and colorize it using a Hue/Saturation clipping mask. That should give you a reasonable approximation of your desired effect. Looks like you'll want to have a blur layer too.